# parsing UniMag II encrypted swipe data to get Track1 and Track 2?

Tags: ios, credit-card-track-data, unimag

I am using a IDTech Shuttle to swipe card data in my iOS app and I need to send Track1 and Track2 as separate values to my card processor.  I have researched getting track1 and track2 data and it looks pretty straight forward except my returned swipe data does not follow the same format as described my all of the posts I have read.

My swipe data looks something like this:

```
J(LbÐðhQRÍm©½gÝD|}xÆÁ°ø)Cc+­%N9;Aq6*ØÉ\ØsÀüÝXþYü;tHÎMHãøÃH¡æ´v­¤æe£õ®;PJá#÷{oö zú5OËáÒðìåÍ.;°¿äT125007331bI$A
 Æ
```

How do I parse that into 2 separate tracks?  I am assuming there is some sort of format here

Comment: Actually, that does not look like track 1 or track 2 data, so I assume it is encrypted somehow.

Comment: @slee , can you share your code how your have read the card details . That would be helpful for every one who is facing same problem like me .  Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDTECH encrypted devices (ED), Shuttle included, are HEX output and HID. You will need to acquire the SDK for the Shuttle specifically as there are 2 output formats for IDTECH ED's and I think the Shuttle uses the newer of the 2.

You can then build a parser which will count the field lengths, some are are just 2 (I believe the first 6 to 8 are) and some are variable with padding to conform to a fixed length.

I believe you can there are 3 fields, track 1 and 2, track 1 and track 2, you would be interested in.